# How precise is tracking movement using accelerometer-Android?

Tags: android

I need to implement some kind of movement tracking in my app and I need it to be precise, as precise as with 1% precision. For example if user moves 5 m, is it possible for app to calculate that user moved (5+-0.05) m using accelerometer? To rephrase my question, does accelerometer give such precise data? I know after that it comes to implementing the sensor and optimising the code. If it is possible, it would be great if you could also link any sort of tutorial or example impementing this kind of tracking.

NOTE: I do not want app to measure steps, but exact distance the user has moved.

Comment: Considering acceleration = delta speed (change in speed) / time it is almost impossible to work out. There can be no change in the acclerometer readings where the user can be travelling at a constant speed.

Comment: Well I could track speed, and not acceleration in each moment. For example, if accel. starts at 0 and it goes to 10 for 2 seconds and then 0 for the rest of duration, I could calculate the speed it accelerated to in those 2 seconds. 0 acceleration means only that there is no change in speed, that said, the speed is the same as in the moment acceleration became 0.

Comment: Then you have the issue of a knock on the device, change of direction, assuming that when the app was started that the user was completely stationary. There are too many variables to be accounted for. GPS will give the best accuracy, and as part of using it, will tell you how accurate it believes it is being.

Comment: True, but it is the best thing I got so far. I'll try to find other options as well. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such precision is not possible to get out of the devices, primarily because they move in such complicated patterns.

What you basically want to do is to perform a double integration of a sampled acceleration signal - to get position. Acceleration signals are by their nature quite... spasmic, meaning that the sampling rate will have to be very high, but even so, will contain errors. These errors will be magnified in the integration process, and so it will be very hard to reconstruct a position with any accuracy. You will get what is known as "drift".

The problem is common and quite well known. https://www.google.com/search?q=double+integration+of+sampled+signal

The solution you want to use is GPS.

Comment: And is GPS able to give such precise measurements? Notice that it is 99% precision, which means if user moved 1 m, I would need with 1cm precision.

Comment: No, the GPS isn't that precise either.